# golang -- cannot convert raw (variable of type []byte) to driver.Value

Tags: go

I'm trying to create a Value function for a jsonb database field, for use by go-pg.

```
func (m JSONMap) Value() (driver.Value, error) {
    raw, err := json.Marshal(m)

    if err != nil {
        return driver.Value(nil), err
    }

    return driver.Value(raw), nil
}
```

This seems to be a pretty standard piece of code. Many more or less identical pieces of code can be found here: https://golang.hotexamples.com/examples/database.sql.driver/-/Value/golang-value-function-examples.html and very similar code can be found in the go-pg tests: https://github.com/go-pg/pg/blob/782c9d35ba243106ba6445fc753c3ac6a14c3324/conv_test.go

But no matter what I do, I get a compiler error: `cannot convert raw (variable of type []byte) to driver.Value`

If I replace `return driver.Value(raw), nil` with `return driver.Value("ABC"), nil` it seems to work just fine. However,

```
str := "ABC"
return driver.Value(str), nil
```

generates a compiler error.

I'm a little lost, any help is appreciated.

Comment: can you create a reproducible example?  It doesn't look like you'd actually need a database connection to reproduce the error, so maybe on the go playground?

Comment: @DanielFarrell ya it does seem to compile successfully in go playground, so it must be something else in the codebase. But I have no idea what.

Comment: Well I restarted my coding environment and everything seems to be fine now. Oh well.

Comment: This seems to happen in the latest go1.19.3

Comment: This is most likely due to go version mismatch. You probably have go packages from 1.19 and compiler 1.18 or 1.17.